# PHP $_SERVER('REQUEST_URI') Showing Unexpected Result (httpd.conf, ssl)

Tags: php, apache, https

NOTE: I am not the system admin, so my knowledge and ability to edit system config files is somewhat limited.

A server that recently went all-Https was not displaying our 404 page like it was before the switch.

> **Not Found**
>
> The requested URL /toh was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

In our httpd.conf page, we had the line

```
ErrorDocument 404 /admin/404/
```

When we changed this line to

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://example.com/admin/404/
```

everything seemed to work fine; the Not Found error went away and the 404 page was properly displayed.

However,

This 404 page detects where the user was originally coming from using

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

The page would then check a database, see if that URI was in there, and would then redirect the client to the appropriate page.

So, for example, if the user came to the page from:

```
http://example.com/tacos
```

In the event that wasn't a valid link, the 404 page would see the /tacos link, find it in a database, and redirect the user where he/she needed to go.

Now, the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] only spits out

```
/admin/404
```

regardless of where the user was coming from.

Comment: try to put the rules that forces a website into https at the top of .htaccess file then clear browser cache and test it

Comment: @Mohammed the rules were set in a .conf file, not an .htaccess file. But it turns out the problem (from what I can tell) was that the RewriteEngine was turned off. Please see my answer for more if so inclined. Thanks.

Comment: what about https://example.com/tacos  if not valid link , but with https , does the web server handle it like what you expected ?

Comment: @Mohammed yes, with the rewrite rules turned on and the domain name taken out of the ErrorDocument, everything behaves as expected from what I can tell

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the problem was twofold:

1) Per this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174361/how-to-keep-uri-in-the-browser-using-errordocument-in-htaccess), the ErrorDocument link must not have the domain name; it must be in the format

```
ErrorDocument 404 /admin/404
```

2) In the .conf file, the  did not have the RewriteEngine turned on; it was commented out. So we uncommented the following rules

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ...

#    RewriteEngine on
#    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
#    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [NC]
#    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
    ...
    RedirectMatch permanent ^(.*)/$ https://www.example.com/$1

</VirtualHost>
```

Now, the 404 page is found and $_SERVER(['REQUEST_URI']) has the appropriate resource.